# I couldn't stop setInterval in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Could you help me that, how can I stop this Interval when I mouseover #headline_image?

```
$("#headline li").live('mouseover', function() { 
var HL = $(this).attr("data-name"); 
$("#headline_image").html("<img src='" + HL  + "'>"); });

setInterval(function()
{ $('#headline li[data-id=' + count + ']').mouseover(); },4000); });
```

I tried as below in `mouseover` function; but it didnt work

```
clearInterval(function()  { $('#headline li').mouseover(); });
```

Comment: What version of jQurey are you using?

Comment: @antindexer im using jquery 1.8.2

Comment: In this case use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the actual timerid from the `setInterval()` call and you pass that to `clearInterval()`.

```
$("#headline li").live('mouseover', function() { 
    var HL = $(this).attr("data-name"); 
    $("#headline_image").html("<img src='" + HL  + "'>"); 
    clearInterval(timerId);
});

var timerId = setInterval(function() { 
    $('#headline li[data-id=' + count + ']').mouseover(); },4000); 
});
```

FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated since version 1.7 of jQuery and even removed from the latest versions of jQuery so you should be using `.on()` in the version 1.8 you are using.

---

If `#headline` is a static object (present initially and not recreated), then you could switch to `.on()` like this:

```
$("#headline").on('mouseover', "li", function() { 
    var HL = $(this).attr("data-name"); 
    $("#headline_image").html("<img src='" + HL  + "'>"); 
    clearInterval(timerId);
});

var timerId = setInterval(function() { 
    $('#headline li[data-id=' + count + ']').mouseover(); },4000); 
});
```

If `#headline` itself is dynamic, then change to:

```
$(static parent).on('mouseover', "#headline li", function() {
```

where you you replace `static parent` with a selector to the closest parent to `#headline` that is itself not dynamic.

---

For references on using `.on()` for dynamic elements see these references:

[jQuery .on does not work but .live does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985090/jquery-on-does-not-work-but-live-does/9985137#9985137)

[Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409)

[Proper use of .on method in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473379/proper-use-of-on-method-in-jquery/9473429#9473429)

Comment: how about start again on mouseout?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - `.live()` is deprecated as of 1.7.  He should NOT be using it.

Comment: dear friends, it didnt start again via this code: $("#headline li").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
clearInterval(interval); var HL = $(this).attr("data-name"); $("#headline_image").html("<img src='" + HL  + "'>"); },

  mouseleave: function(){  setInterval(interval); }

});

Comment: @user3147942 - please see what I've added to my answer.  You need to use the dynamic form of `.on()`, not the static form.

Comment: @user3147942 - yes, please read my answer - you are using the static way of using `.on()`, not the dynamic way.

Comment: @user3147942 - I've added several references to my answer that help explain how to use `.on()` for dynamic elements.  Please don't paste multiline code into comments because it isn't readable.  I gave you an exact example in my answer for how to get the dynamic behavior with `.on()`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the reference returned by setInterval to clear it

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $('#headline li[data-id=' + count + ']').mouseover();
}, 4000);
```

then

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

also make sure the declare the variable interval in a scope shared by both these pieces of code

Comment: i couldnt start again via $("#headline li").live('mouseover', function() { clearInterval(interval);
var HL = $(this).attr("data-name"); 
$("#headline_image").html("<img src='" + HL  + "'>"); },
  mouseleave: function(){  setInterval(interval); });